# Coloring chord diagrams based on group with Bokeh and Holoviews

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

all.
I'm having some trouble with the [Holoviews library documentation](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/Chord.html).
I have two `pd dataframes`, one defining all the connections I want to see in my Chord Diagram:

```
conns = pd.DataFrame(links)
print(conns)


        from      to  value parent
0     01.110  01.120      1      A
1     01.110  01.130      1      A
2     01.110  01.190      1      A
3     01.110  01.260      1      A
4     01.130  01.190      1      A
...      ...     ...    ...    ...
1319  96.090  88.910      1      S
1320  96.090  90.010      1      S
1321  96.090  93.190      1      S
1322  96.090  96.010      1      S
1323  99.000  84.210      1      U
```

if I plot the chord diagram with
hv.Chord(conns), I get the following plot:
[image: Plot result for hv.Chord(chonns)]

Which is what I want, however, **I want to add coloring based on the 'parent' and if possible, add te parent value to the tooltips**. I've been busting my head on this and the results I can get is the following:

code:

```
hv.Chord(conns, ['from', 'to'], ['value', 'parent']).opts(
opts.Chord(cmap='Category20', edge_color=dim('parent').astype(str)))
```

[image: Best result]

However, adding the argument `node_color=dim('parent').astype(str)))` in `opts` throws an Error: `ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Color)) or Color, got dim('parent').astype(dtype=<class 'str'>)`

As far as I understand the way to go should be by using the `hv.Dataset` object, which I'm constructing like this, but I don't know how to pass it to the hv.Chord()

```
nn_d = nn_d[['index', 'parent']]
nodes = hv.Dataset(nn_d, ['index'], ['parent'])
print(nn_d)


        index parent
0      01.110      A
1      01.130      A
2      01.140      A
3      01.150      A
4      01.190      A
...       ...    ...
10159  96.022      S
10160  96.030      S
10161  96.040      S
10162  96.090      S
10163  99.000      U
```